# Java Arraylist Heap Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures, heap

I am trying to implement an `insert()` method for an arraylist-based heap implementation, but whenever I test the method inserting more than one integer where at least one of them is greater than ~4 the program takes forever to run. For example, stating `heap.insert(1)` and `heap.insert(8)` together in the main function will take forever to run. Here is my heap class:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Heap<E extends Comparable<E>> implements HeapAPI<E>
{
    /**
     * A complete tree stored in an array list representing this
     * binary heap
     */
    private ArrayList<E> tree;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty heap
     */
    public Heap()
    {
        tree = new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
       return tree.isEmpty();
    }

    public void insert(E obj)
    {
        tree.add(tree.size(), obj);
        siftUp(tree.size() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * siftUp from position k. The key or node value at position
     * may be greater that that of its parent at k/2.
     * @param k position in the heap arraylist
     */
    private void siftUp(int k)
    {
        E v = tree.get(k);
        while (v.compareTo(tree.get(k / 2)) == 1)
        {
            tree.add(k, tree.get(k / 2));
            k = k / 2;
        }
        tree.add(k, v);
    }

    public int size()
    {
       return tree.size();
    }
}
```

This is the pseudocode given to us by my professor that I modeled the `insert()` and `siftUp()` methods from:
[image: Pseudocode for Methods]

The program works for small integers, for example, if I type  `heap.insert(1)` a bunch of times in a row, but never finishes running if I change one of the numbers to a larger integer. No errors are thrown, as it doesn't finish executing when I try to run the program. I'm not sure what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tip: when you are *not sure* what your program is doing; learn how to use a debugger. Or at least: put in some print statements. Because that makes your code **observable**. And it is hard to guess what your code is doing, as your not giving **all** the code necessary to repro the issue.

Comment: You may want to use `tree.set` rather than `tree.add` to set the value of the `ArrayList` at a particular index.  Otherwise, the new element is inserted into the position (shifting subsequent elements to the right), rather than replacing the existing value at that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through your code here for a moment:

```
public void insert(E obj)
{
    tree.add(tree.size(), obj);
    siftUp(tree.size() - 1);
}

private void siftUp(int k)
{
    E v = tree.get(k);
    while (v.compareTo(tree.get(k / 2)) == 1)
    {
        tree.add(k, tree.get(k / 2));
        k = k / 2;
    }
    tree.add(k, v);
}
```

Now, you do the `tree.insert(1)`, and everything works fine. Next you call `tree.insert(0)`. Let's see what happens.

- `tree.add(tree.size(), obj)` adds 0 as the next item in the array list. So you now have a list that contains `[1, 0]`
- the code calls `siftUp(1)`
- in `siftUp`, the first line gets element 1 from the array list. At this point, `v = 1`
- at the `while` statement, the code compares the value, 1, to the value at `tree[k/2]`. Since `k == 1`, you're checking against the root node (i.e. `tree[0]`), which we know is equal to 1.
- Because the new value is smaller than its parent, you copy the parent value to the new item's position. At this point, your array list contains `[1, 1]`.
- You divide your index, `k`, by 2, giving 0.
- Now you're back to the `while` condition. `k` is equal to 0 and the value at `tree[k]` is 1, meaning that it's still greater than the value of v.
- You're now in an infinite loop, continually comparing the value at index 0 with your temporary value.

The problem is that your loop has no definite ending condition.

One way to solve the problem is to end the loop if `k == 0`.

```
private void siftUp(int k)
{
    E v = tree.get(k);
    while (k > 0 && v.compareTo(tree.get(k / 2)) == 1)
    {
        tree.add(k, tree.get(k / 2));
        k = k / 2;
    }
    tree.add(k, v);
}
```

The next trouble you're going to have is that your calculation of the parent node is incorrect. If the root node of the heap is at index 0, then for a node at index `ix`, its left child is at `(ix*2)+1`, and the right child is at `(ix*2)+2`. The node's parent is at `(ix-1)/2`.

Consider the heap with three nodes:

```
        0
      1   2
```

Here the node numbers are the same as the array indexes.

If the root is at index 0, then the left node is at (2 * 0) + 1. The right node is at (2 * 0) + 2. The parent of 1 is (1-1)/2. And the parent of 2 is (2-1)/2. In your code, you parent calculation is `k/2`, which would give an incorrect value of 1 for the node labeled 2 in the heap above.